# list of vaadin's special path variables @JavaScript(value = { "vaadin://...", "???://..." }

Tags: java, javascript, annotations, vaadin

I try to add js file to output html code in vaadin7.4.13+maven project.
I know that it is possible to use `vaadin://...` *protocol* which is translated to `/VAADIN/` directory.

Now I know that this isn't the only one trick it can be used there because I've seen some other *protocols* being used in @JavaScript annotation but I cannot recall them. Please help me with this.

1. vaadin://
2. ???://
3. ???://
4. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at vaadin's source code of `com.vaadin.shared.ApplicationConstants` I found out these:

```
APP_PATH = "APP";
UIDL_PATH = "UIDL";
HEARTBEAT_PATH = "HEARTBEAT";
PUSH_PATH = "PUSH";
PUBLISHED_FILE_PATH = APP_PATH + '/' + "PUBLISHED";
APP_PROTOCOL_PREFIX = "app://";
VAADIN_PROTOCOL_PREFIX = "vaadin://";
FONTICON_PROTOCOL_PREFIX = "fonticon://";
PUBLISHED_PROTOCOL_NAME = "published";
PUBLISHED_PROTOCOL_PREFIX = PUBLISHED_PROTOCOL_NAME + "://";
```